# Fault/error/failure in this example

Tags: testing, computer-science, terminology

Having following general definitions:
**fault** - a cause of the error (mistake in coding)
**error** - incorrect state that may lead to failure
**failure** - deviation of the service from the correct service

What would be the correct application on the following code:

The code should not allow withdrawal when there is a balance of 100 or less

```
  if (Balance<100) 
    {
    return false; 
    }
    else WithDraw();
```

So as I understand it, the fault is the missing = operator. But what will be the error and failure?

Comment: Simple example of fault, error, failure: A method is supposed to return an array with 100 random numbers in it, but due to a fault in the code, it sometimes erroneously returns an array with 101 random numbers in it. However the method that asked for the array assumes there is 100 elements `for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)` so it never notices the error, and neither is there any failure. (If the error had resulted in 99 elements there would have been a failure, but as it were the rest of the code did not fail despite the error in this example.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a fault (coding or logic mistake) in the code as you said, the missing operator in the comparison. It is possible that no-one ever notices this mistake if there never is balance of exactly 100.

If at some point there is a balance of 100 and the check is done, the error will be exposed. The system will be in incorrect state. It should not have allowed withdrawal, but instead it did. If the withdrawal is allowed, the system is failing to work as it should and user sees the failure.

In this small example it is hard to separate error and failure as the user would probably see the consequences of the error state. If we assume that there is another check somewhere else in the code and because of that the withdrawal is not done, then the system would have been in wrong state (error actualized), but another condition would have masked this one and user would have not seen the failure.

Comment: thank you, I have asked few times and your answer is the best so far I have recieved. Would you be able to make an example where an error occurrs but do not immediately leads to a failure?

Comment: I edited your question a little (producing quite horrible code) to make it easier to explain and modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but didnt you make a mistake? You said when balance is 100, BalanceOK got value false, but this is not the case according to the code.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I don't now see easy way to make this example work without making it even more horrible. Maybe it is better to revert back to your original question.

Comment: I just changed the requirements, looks fine now :) I would be greateful for even absolutey different example ;)

Comment: Actually, it is still not ok. With balance 100 now it is allowing withdrawals even though it shouldn't and changing the second if clause won't mask this error. I still suggest that we go back to original form.

Comment: Ok, done. Please note its about not allowing when value is 100 or less.

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe my answer now really answers the question. :-)

Comment: Thanks, however, I still see the original answer :) But it did help. I would just need to see an example when an error does nto cause failure immediately. Also if there was additional check in the Withdrawal method, the system would eventually work fine, however that error would be present, right?

Answer (score -3):

This question needs some context. It also seems to be a 'homework' style question.
From the definitions provided, a 'missing = operator' may not be the 'fault'.

The variable 'Balance' being tested may explicitly need to be less than 100.

As for an error, you are referring to 'state'. In this regard, you may have to look to previous control flow statements (if/for/while) to assess the state.

Failures...well, perhaps you are dealing with simple conversion errors (int/float) which are common when dealing with a currency orientated program.

When referring to code not doing what it is supposed to be doing, we normally refer to:

- compile/run time error
- logic error

Comment: The missing operator is definitely the fault because it is the coding mistake that will lead to error.. Pls read this or dependability definitons